# Conflicting AJAX & JQuery Scripts - No Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem starting a script from an AJAX called query.

The AJAX is working fine and loading posts, but it stops the ".jobs-button" from being able to run the desired script. Strangely, if I set this to another element outside of the AJAX called query block, then the script works fine.

Any ideas why ".jobs-button" does not fire within the "hide/show" script?

Here's a demo incase my explanation isn't clear: http://pixeldesigns.uk/ardour/jobs

This first script, is a simple "show/hide":

```
jQuery(".jobs-button").toggle(function () {
    jQuery(".jobs-main").slideDown(500);
    jQuery(".jobs-head")
        .delay(500)
        .queue(function () {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("jobs-closed");
            jQuery(this).addClass("jobs-open");
            jQuery(this).dequeue();
        });

    jQuery(".fa-chevron-down")
        .delay(500)
        .queue(function () {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("rotate");
            jQuery(this).addClass("rotated");
            jQuery(this).dequeue();
        });
    jQuery(".jobs-intro, .jobs-desc, .jobs-qual, .jobs-bul").delay(500).animate({
        'opacity': 1
    }, 500);
}, function () {
    jQuery(".jobs-main").delay(500).slideUp(500);
    jQuery(".jobs-head")
        .delay(1000)
        .queue(function () {
            jQuery(this).addClass("jobs-closed");
            jQuery(this).removeClass("jobs-open");
            jQuery(this).dequeue();
        });

    jQuery(".fa-chevron-down")
        .delay(1000)
        .queue(function () {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("rotated");
            jQuery(this).addClass("rotate");
            jQuery(this).dequeue();
        });

    jQuery(".jobs-intro, .jobs-desc, .jobs-qual, .jobs-bul").animate({
        'opacity': 0
    }, 500);
});
```

The second runs AJAX to call a script on page load and on button click which runs a query and bring across the correct posts:

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    jQuery('#load').show();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/ajax/sales.php",
        type: "get",
        success: function (e) {
            document.getElementById("tab-1").innerHTML = e;
            jQuery('#load').hide();
        },
        error: function (e, t) {
            e.status > 0 && (document.getElementById("tab-1").innerHTML = "Error: " + t);
        }
    })
});

jQuery("#tb-1").click(function () {
    jQuery('#load').show();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/ajax/sales.php",
        type: "get",
        success: function (e) {
            document.getElementById("tab-1").innerHTML = e;
            jQuery('#load').hide();
        },
        error: function (e, t) {
            e.status > 0 && (document.getElementById("tab-1").innerHTML = "Error: " + t);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Firebug I picked up that this piece of code is giving an error because there is no element "#flow". Maybe this code is not needed on this page as it is for a flow chart?

```
// Flow Chart

            jQuery.ajax(jQuery(window).width()<989?{url:"http://pixeldesigns.uk/ardour/wp-content/themes/ardour/ajax/flow-small.php",type:"get",success:function(e){document.getElementById("flow").innerHTML=e},error:function(e,n){e.status>0&&(document.getElementById("flow").innerHTML="Error: "+n)}}:{url:"http://pixeldesigns.uk/ardour/wp-content/themes/ardour/ajax/flow-big.php",type:"get",success:function(e){document.getElementById("flow").innerHTML=e},error:function(e,n){e.status>0&&(document.getElementById("flow").innerHTML="Error: "+n)}});
```